# Java не импортирует библиотеку JavaFX

Tags: java, linux, javafx, intellij-idea

После автоматического создания в Intellij IDEA проекта JavaFX приложения, при запуске компилятор Java выводит следующее сообщение:

```
`/home/greenmiler/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/main/java/sample/Main.java
Error:(1, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist
Error:(2, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
Error:(3, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(4, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
Error:(5, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
Error:(7, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Application
Error:(10, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Stage
  location: class Main
Error:(9, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(11, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Parent
  location: class Main
Error:(11, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class Main
Error:(11, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FXMLLoader
  location: class Main
Error:(13, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scene
  location: class Main
Error:(19, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method launch(java.lang.String[])
  location: class Main`
```

Как я понимаю Java может не импортировать JavaFX, но почему? В системе установлена Oracle JDK 11 в которую должна быть включена библиотека JavaFX, или я ошибаюсь? Также пробовал запускать на JDK c пакета openjdk-11-jdk и установленной JavaFX командой `apt install openjfx-*`, но вывод не изменился.
Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Теперь с 11 версии чтобы запустить JavaFx приложение надо иметь jar-ку размером 40мб, со всеми зависимостимя и для каждой платформы еще и javaFx sdk по 100 мб. Качайте 8 версию. Любую до 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начиная с версий после 8 JavaFX выделена в отдельный проект OpenJFX, соответственно вместе с JDK больше не поставляется. В своё время, для запуска проекта на JavaFX и OpenJDK 11, я черпал информацию [отсюда](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Ошибаетесь. В Oracle JDK 11 JavaFX не входит, её надо ставить отдельно. Хотите иметь JavaFX в комплекте, ставьте Oracle JDK 8.
2. После установки новой JDK в систему, если вы не удалили ранее установленную предыдущую версию, необходимо произвести настройку - какая из установленных ранее JDK будет использоваться системой по-умолчанию. Выполните команду `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, выберите из установленных JDK/JVM, ту которую вы хотите назначить по умолчанию, проверьте настройки `java -version` См. здесь [Choosing the default Java to use](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) с картинками.